# How to run methods when user double touched

Tags: android, touch

There is some method, so I need to find out touch by user. For example after double touching InputBox by user run the following method

For touching should to use

> > > > TouchListener

```
private void DoubleTouched(){
    //Do Some Things
}
```

So how do we find out user double zouched, I means user takes one touch after touch and not multi-touch.

Comment: Try OnDoubleTapListener http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener to your activity

```
public class GestureDetectionActivity extends Activity implements GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener{
```

and override this method

```
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
       // Do stuff  
       return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this class to get double click

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class SimpleGestureFilter extends SimpleOnGestureListener{

         public final static int SWIPE_UP    = 1;
         public final static int SWIPE_DOWN  = 2;
         public final static int SWIPE_LEFT  = 3;
         public final static int SWIPE_RIGHT = 4;

         public final static int MODE_TRANSPARENT = 0;
         public final static int MODE_SOLID       = 1;
         public final static int MODE_DYNAMIC     = 2;

         private final static int ACTION_FAKE = -13; //just an unlikely number
         private int swipe_Min_Distance = 100;
         private int swipe_Max_Distance = 350;
         private int swipe_Min_Velocity = 100;

     private int mode             = MODE_DYNAMIC;
     private boolean running      = true;
     private boolean tapIndicator = false;

     private Activity context;
     private GestureDetector detector;
     private SimpleGestureListener listener;

     public SimpleGestureFilter(Activity context,SimpleGestureListener sgl) {

      this.context = context;
      this.detector = new GestureDetector(context, this);
      this.listener = sgl;
     }

     public void onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

       if(!this.running)
      return; 

       boolean result = this.detector.onTouchEvent(event);

       if(this.mode == MODE_SOLID)
        event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
       else if (this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC) {

         if(event.getAction() == ACTION_FAKE)
           event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP);
         else if (result)

           event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
         else if(this.tapIndicator){
          event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
          this.tapIndicator = false;
         }

       }
       //else just do nothing, it's Transparent
     }

     public void setMode(int m){
      this.mode = m;
     }

     public int getMode(){
      return this.mode;
     }

     public void setEnabled(boolean status){
      this.running = status;
     }

     public void setSwipeMaxDistance(int distance){
      this.swipe_Max_Distance = distance;
     }

     public void setSwipeMinDistance(int distance){
      this.swipe_Min_Distance = distance;
     }

     public void setSwipeMinVelocity(int distance){
      this.swipe_Min_Velocity = distance;
     }

     public int getSwipeMaxDistance(){
      return this.swipe_Max_Distance;
     }

     public int getSwipeMinDistance(){
      return this.swipe_Min_Distance;
     }

     public int getSwipeMinVelocity(){
      return this.swipe_Min_Velocity;
     }

     @Override
         public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
           float velocityY) {

          final float xDistance = Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX());
          final float yDistance = Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY());

          if(xDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance || yDistance > this.swipe_Max_Distance)
           return false;

          velocityX = Math.abs(velocityX);
          velocityY = Math.abs(velocityY);
                boolean result = false;

          if(velocityX > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && xDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance){
           if(e1.getX() > e2.getX()) // right to left
            this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_LEFT);
           else
            this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_RIGHT);

           result = true;
          }
          else if(velocityY > this.swipe_Min_Velocity && yDistance > this.swipe_Min_Distance){
           if(e1.getY() > e2.getY()) // bottom to up
            this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_UP);
           else
            this.listener.onSwipe(SWIPE_DOWN);

           result = true;
          }

           return result;
         }

     @Override
     public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
      this.tapIndicator = true;
      return false;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent arg) {
      this.listener.onDoubleTap();;
      return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent arg) {
      return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent arg) {

      if(this.mode == MODE_DYNAMIC){        // we owe an ACTION_UP, so we fake an
         arg.setAction(ACTION_FAKE);      //action which will be converted to an ACTION_UP later.
         this.context.dispatchTouchEvent(arg);
      }  

      return false;
     }

        static  interface SimpleGestureListener{
         void onSwipe(int direction);
         void onDoubleTap();
     }

    }
```

In your Activity Implements this as like

```
  import com.xevoke.securemessage.SimpleGestureFilter.SimpleGestureListener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class UseGesture extends Activity implements SimpleGestureListener {
     private SimpleGestureFilter detector;
     GestureDetector gestureDetector;

     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        detector = new SimpleGestureFilter(this,this);
    }
      @Override
        public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){
            // Call onTouchEvent of SimpleGestureFilter class
             this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
           return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
        }
    @Override
    public void onSwipe(int direction) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Debug swipe","into swipe "+direction);
          String str = "";

          switch (direction) {

        case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_RIGHT:



            break;
          case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_LEFT : 
              str = "Swipe Left";


              break;
          case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_DOWN : 
              str = "Swipe Down";

              break;
          case SimpleGestureFilter.SWIPE_UP : 
              str = "Swipe Up";

              break;

          }
          Log.e("Debug Swipe",str);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDoubleTap() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "Double Tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 //Do you stuff into this mehtod
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@override` method to detect double dap

```
@Override
    public void onDoubleTap() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Do your stub here
    }
```